# How can I edit the information of a SoundCloud attachment in a Facebook post?

Tags: facebook, soundcloud

I posted:

[image]

Is there anyway to edit the post to change the title of the SoundCloud track "sp1n DJs - Mix MIT GSC Boat Cruise - 23 - 05 - 2014" to something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot edit the information of a SoundCloud attachment in a Facebook post.